# RDFLib or rdflib-sqlalchemy: graph.remove function fails silently

Tags: python, django, rdflib

I am in the process of building out a Django-based semantic application using rdflib-sqlalchemy to handle translation between triplestore and database logic. I can't really tell whether the issue is with rdflib-sqlalchemy or with RDFLib itself, but when I attempt to remove triples from within the Django application, there is no effect on the triples portion of the database, and the graph returns an identical count of triples before and after the delete attempt. If I try the same procedure from the Python console (same VirtualEnv, same base data, but different database), the graph.remove() function works as expected. I don't see anything on SO that even closely resembles this, but I could be missing something.

So, for instance, the following works as a means of deleting all the triples with https://url.to/scheme/MADAGASCAR as the subject:

```
>>> g
<Graph identifier=foo (<class 'rdflib.graph.ConjunctiveGraph'>)>
>>> g.store
<Partitioned SQL N3 Store>
>>> len(list(g.triples(('https://url.to/scheme/MADAGASCAR',None,None))))
11
>>> g.remove(('https://url.to/scheme/MADAGASCAR',None,None))
>>> len(list(g.triples(('https://url.to/scheme/MADAGASCAR',None,None))))
0
```

Similarly, I can use the same methods from inside my Django interactive console:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> from rdflib_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy import SQLAlchemy
>>> from semantic.models import Namespace, AssertionStatement, LiteralStatement, QuotedStatement, TypeStatement, Resource
>>> g = settings.GRAPH
>>> len(list(g.triples(('https://url.to/scheme/MADAGASCAR',None,None))))
11
>>> g.remove(('https://url.to/scheme/MADAGASCAR',None,None))
>>> len(list(g.triples(('https://url.to/scheme/MADAGASCAR',None,None))))
0
```

But when I call it from within a Signal, there is no effect. Before I post the Signal code, let me briefly describe my approach for managing triples, which are effectively compound keys (something for which Django lacks support). What I've done is created a single Django-managed model to list out Resources (e.g., anything that can be an owl:NamedIndividual, so neither predicates nor literals) and five unmanaged models that map to rdflib-sqlalchemy's database tables (which include id (pk) fields as of 4ee1791). Populating the store via a management command makes use of rdflib-sqlalchemy to put the data in the right unmanaged tables, after which I iterate through the TypeStatements and get the unique set of resources to populate the managed Resource table. This in turn drives a portion of the admin interface so that it's possible to manage Resources in a unified way as a workaround for the lack of compound key support.

Now, everything in my admin interface works for listing purposes. So I wanted to add a delete function that would mimic a cascade delete such that if you delete a Resource object, it deletes all triples with that Resource as subject and all triples with that Resources as object. My research on how to interject with additional functions attached to the object delete function led me to Signals. Below is the Signal I created for pre_delete of a Resource object. I have added console logging simply to aid in debugging; the output of that also follows.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, pre_delete, post_save, post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings
from semantic.models import Namespace, AssertionStatement, LiteralStatement, QuotedStatement, TypeStatement, Resource
from rdflib_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy import SQLAlchemy
from rdflib import ConjunctiveGraph, URIRef

graph = settings.GRAPH

# When something is deleted from the Resource table, we want to delete all of its associated inbound and outbound triples
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Resource)
def model_pre_change(sender, **kwargs):
  print("Before delete, the graph has %s triples" % len(graph))
  print("There are %s " % len(list(graph.triples((kwargs['instance'].__str__(),None,None)))) + "triples associated with %s " % kwargs['instance'].__str__())

  # Not sure why graph.remove(triple_or_quad) doesn't seem to work...
  graph.remove((kwargs['instance'].__str__(),None,None))
  graph.remove((None,None,kwargs['instance'].__str__()))


@receiver(post_delete, sender=Resource)
def model_post_change(sender, **kwargs):
  # This is for debugging only.
  print("After delete, the graph has %s triples" % len(graph))
  print("There are %s " % len(list(graph.triples((kwargs['instance'].__str__(),None,None)))) + "triples associated with %s " % kwargs['instance'].__str__())
```

And the log output:

```
Before delete, the graph has 2178 triples
There are 11 triples associated with https://url.to/scheme/MADAGASCAR
After delete, the graph has 2178 triples
There are 11 triples associated with https://url.to/scheme/MADAGASCAR
```

The Resource model object gets deleted as expected, but the triples remain in the store.

So the question is how do I get this to actually work? Am I doing something wrong in my Signals?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't think it mattered, but I was using sqlite for my database. With no error messages, it didn't occur to me that the database gets locked while the Django wsgi is running. This doesn't seem to happen under the Django interactive console, which is why the function worked there with no issue.

Anyway I switched to PostgreSQL and the logic works as expecetd now. I guess my setup relies on multiple simultaneous connections to the database, which is fine as long as rdflib-sqlalchemy is just going to read the store.